# Selenium python login working locally but not on Linux server

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login into following website through selenium python

```
https://www.talentwise.com/screening/login.php
```

when I enter username, password and click sigin everything gets all cleared without any error message on ui.(Code is working fine locally,but not on our Linux server)

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    options.add_argument("window-size=1200,1100")
    options.binary_location = "parts/chromium/chromium/chrome"
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        chrome_options=options,
        executable_path='parts/chromium/chromedriver/chromedriver',
    )
    self.driver.maximize_window()
    self.driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='EmailAddr']")
        )
    ).send_keys(username)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='Password']")
        )
    ).send_keys(password)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, delay).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "//input[@id='SignIn' and @type='submit' and @value='Sign In']")
        )
    ).click()
```

Comment: Which error did you receive? Does your script use virtualdisplay?

Comment: no, there are no errors. Just username and password fields get cleared out on clicking sigin. No not using any kind of script.

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email Address* and *Password* field you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.talentwise.com/screening/login.php')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#EmailAddr"))).send_keys("OmkarSalgaonkar@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#Password").send_keys("OmkarSalgaonkar")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#SignIn").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.talentwise.com/screening/login.php')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='EmailAddr']"))).send_keys("OmkarSalgaonkar@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='Password']").send_keys("OmkarSalgaonkar")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='SignIn']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: sterling]

Comment: Hi Debanjan,
Thanks for your answer and your time really appreciated it.
As you said I have already used  "WebDriverWait" and I am able to Login on my local machine, But when I push my code to our Linux server it dose not (like clicking on signing button will clear my username password).
 Do I need some additional libs on our Linux server ?

Comment: @OmkarSalgaonkar _WebDriverWait_ is a vast topic. Please go through the answer and the embedded links once again. The code block within my answer should work irrespective of [tag:os] platforms.